# UISearchBar covers the status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I have created a `UISearchBar`, when i start editing the search bar the navigation bar is hidden and search bar should be just below the status bar but in my case search bar is covering the status bar.

Code to get the action-

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

}
```

**ScreenShots:**

Shown as:
[image]

Required:
[image]

Comment: How do you position your search bar? Did you have a constraint pinning it to the navigation bar? You should constrain it to the top layout guide.

Comment: there is no constraint pinning to navigation bar, search bar is related to table view

Comment: Is it table view controller or you added table view in view controller. And are you using Auto layout?

Comment: Try unchecking table extends under top bars in IB for the tableView.